# Communication between servicestack instances

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have 3 servers, each hosting single servicestack REST service. They are connected in a chain. I would like to make some data replication via message passing. Is there any message passing mechanism in servicestack ? Or maybe I should use some third party tool ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use any of the [.NET ServiceClients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) and call it remote service directly, e.g:

```
var remoteService = new JsonServiceClient(remoteBaseUrl);
var response = remoteService.Post(new Request { ... })
```

You can also use a [Redis MQ or RabbitMQ host](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging) and register handlers in the Remote Service host.

Depending on your use-case you may also be able to take advantage of the [ServerEvents .NET Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-Server-Events-Client) support to listen for events on a persistent connection with the remote instance.

Also the built-in [Pub/Sub support in Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#new-managed-pubsub-server) makes a good remote IPC solution between servers.